# Best way to add seed to Perlin noise?

Tags: c++, perlin-noise, random-seed

I'm trying to implement 2D Perlin noise generation in C++, and some implementations I found use no seed at all ([here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/66480-perlin-noise/), [here](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973369/software-perlin-noise-implementation)). Other implementations take a seed value to get different noise depending on the noise value.

However I found [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753055/perlin-noise-generation-for-terrain) where one added the seed value to the function parameters calculating the noise value for each octave (see PerlinNoise::Total() in the linked code). Another one uses a 3D seed function and uses the fixed seed value as the z value (couldn't find the example just now). Other articles suggest using other noise functions.

So my question would be, what the best way would be to add a seed value to Perlin noise generation is. Given the same seed value, the same noise values should be generated. If the solution would be to have a custom noise function, I would be interested if it could be implemented using Boost.Random (or C++11's Standard C++ Library classes).

Edit: To answer what I mean with "best" way: What's the best way that gives me Perlin noise like it was supposed to work, e.g. a gradient noise function.

Comment: None of the cited sources are implementations of genuine Perlin Noise. The real deal can be found [here](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/).

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Fastest, least memory, most interesting noise, etc.... I've used libnoise (http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/) which has a variety of noise types with seed values.

Comment: Google for Simplex Noise.  The Simplex Noise function looks a lot like Perlin and has some properties that are preferable to Perlin Noise.  The randomness is in the look-up table, that you can seed when you generate it.

Comment: If boost random allows you to have pseudo randon generation I do not see why not. What's important si that for a set of values, we always have the same value returned each time, otherwise it's complete randomness and it won't work. I did a small perlin noise demo once, I generated random numbers (with some other tools) and created 2d array (since I was working in 2d) on the fly, where for a position, I set up one of my random value (randomly), if the position is not already initialized.

Comment: I hacked together a seeded Perlin from the original Ken Perlin code with some small tweaking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213469/best-way-to-add-seed-to-perlin-noise

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since no one is going to write up an answer from the comments, I'm trying myself. Please upvote when I'm correct, comment when not :)

There are several implementations and example code that (try to) implement Perlin noise. First, there is the [Improved Noise reference implementation](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) from Ken Perlin himself.

### Case 1: Improved Noise reference implementation

The noise function takes three double values and outputs a value. When generating a 2D bitmap using x and y, and keeping z constant, one gets the well known Perlin noise pattern. When z is varied between 0.0 and 1.0, the noise clouds seem to "change" slowly. So a seeding method that sets z, e.g. `z = 10.0 * seed`, could work for "seeding".

Another way to seed the noise function would be this: If you always just get noise in a range of [0.0; 64.0[ for x and y, one could seed the noise by adding an offset to x, y or both when calling the noise function: noise(x + 64.0*seed, y + 64.0*seed).

### Case 2: Tutorial style Perlin noise code

Then there is an [implementation](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) of Perlin noise (adapted and used in many other Perlin noise tutorials) that have a base noise function like this (pseudocode):

```
function Noise2(integer x, integer y)
    n = x + y * 57
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589)
       & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    
end function
```

My main skepticism came from the magic numbers and the trust of the authors of these pages that the formula leads to uniformly distributed noise. Other authors added the seed value somewhere in this formula.

The solution to add a seed to this type of Perlin noise implementation is to write a function that uniformly distributes output values for given x and y values (and by returning the same value for the same x and y values, of course). This function can be written using Boost.Random (code not tested):

```
double Noise2(int x, int y)
{
   uint32_t seeds[3] = { uint32_t(x), uint32_t(y), seed };
   boost::mt19937 rng(seeds, seeds+3);
   boost::uniform_real<> dist(0.0, 1.0);
   boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_real<> >
      die(rng, dist);
   return die();
}
```

The random number generator has some ctors, among them one that takes a range of uint32_t's that determine the initial state of the RNG.

There also are libraries that generate coherent noise, such as [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/), that may be of help here.

### Simplex Noise

I didn't ask of Simplex noise, but the one [implementation (from Stefan Gustavson)](http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf) I found uses a similar technique (some precomputed tables) like Ken Perlin's reference implementation, and could be seeded just like case 1 above. Commenter Robinson mentioned seeding when generating the look-up table, but I don't know how that would work.

Comment: The permutation table from Perlin's improved implementation is not special magic.  That's a nice place to seed, in my opinion: just produce your own permutation table by shuffling the numbers from 1 to 256.  This is what @Robinson was talking about in the OP comments.

Comment: @JamesClark: 256 or 255? In [this implementation](https://code.google.com/p/battlestar-tux/source/browse/procedural/simplexnoise.py) [1, 255] was used.

Comment: Good point, but it looks like there's a 0 in that _perm, so [0,255].